# No sound with Stremio / Kodi

Tags: audio, kodi

I installed Kodi in the past which worked fine (including audio).

After a reinstall of my PC I reinstalled Kodi and everything works except I do not have sound. I have sound on all other programs so far (IE, Chrome, some MP3 players, Media player etc). All except Kodi.

So I tried to install Stremio. And I have the exact same problem (no sound).

What I tried:

- Removing/uninstalling all sound devices I don't use (and only kept my USB audio interface Behringer UMC4040HD which I use for all sound)
- Reinstalling Kodi
- On Kodi, trying different settings (forwarding audio, fixed/automated etc).
- On Streamio, there are no relevant sound settings to be filled in.
- Tried one series, one movie, both no sound (on both Kodi/Stremio).

So I wonder what is the problem behind it (and how to solve it). It's not a hardware problem, and both Kodi AND Streamio have the same issue.

**UPDATE**

I used now not the USB device but direct headphones out ... a pity because it worked before I reinstalled my PC.

Comment: Doesn’t seem to like USB drivers.. what does KODI.log say?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 KODI log doesn't show anything (enabled specifically the audio logging).